# how to attach furring strips to drywall (for pegboard installation)

Tags: drywall

I am planning to attach 4'x6' pegboard to drywall in my garage. One vertical end of the frame will be directly screwed into a stud but the other end can't be. I am wondering what kind of screws should be used for the hollow part.

Most drywall anchors or the toggle bolts seem to have a round head which would prevent the pegboard from butting against the frame. Unless the screws attaching the frame to the drywall are completely countersunken, there would be a gap between the pegboard and the frame.

What would be a right way of attaching the furring strip to the drywall?

Comment: Place your furring strips horizontal so that they cross multiple studs. Then you can screw into each stud with simple flat head counter sunk screws.

Comment: Why not drill a hole big enough for the screw head in the furring strips so the head ends up even with the surface?  Your strip will be 4' long, so there's plenty of room for multiple fasteners to give the needed strength.

Answer (score 1):

That's large enough that there's no excuse for trying to hang it from the drywall. Find the studs and drive screws into them.

Comment: Yeah don't worry about being right on the end. Just find the nearest stud to the end and fasten to that. You might also hit a couple studs in the middle depending on the load you plan to put on the board.

Answer (score 0):

For mine, I built a 4'x8' frame out of 1"x2" furring strips, then mounted the peg board to that - drilling pilot holes through the strips, for mounting to the wall studs. There is one additional 1x2, splitting the frame into two 4' x 4' sections, for strength. The drywall screws, that you see in the picture, are 1-1/2" or shorter, for affixing the peg board to the frame. I used longer cabinet screws, for mounting the whole assembly to the wall.

This frame has been moved twice - once in a move, and once from a basement to a garage - easier than hanging a picture. The lone cabinet screw, in the last picture, was just used to hold it on the wall, while I squared it up, and secured the other screws, around the frame.

[image: pegboard-1]
[image: pegboard-2]
[image: pegboard-3]